# Check if file or path [Python]

Tags: python, file, path, operating-system, comparison

I'm trying to find out if its a path or a file.

I tried it with the os lib from python.

```
path = '/home/User/Desktop/file.txt'
isFile = os.path.isfile(path)
print(isFile) -> False
```

Why do I get false and not true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.path.isfile will return False if the file doesn't exist. You might want to check `os.path.exists(path)` as well.